# Python: Flask loading venv with sh

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, sh

I'm trying to launch a server and load a venv with modules installed. So basically I did a start.sh file which is:

```
export FLASK_APP=wsgi.py
export SECRET_KEY=test
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
export APP_CONFIG_FILE=config.py
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=80
which python3
flask run
```

which python3 - usr/bin/python3

And my config.py file which is:

```
"""Set Flask configuration vars from .env file."""

# General Config
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
FLASK_APP = os.environ.get('FLASK_APP')
FLASK_ENV = os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV')
FLASK_DEBUG = os.environ.get('FLASK_DEBUG')
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(minutes=30)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS')
```

So basically I launch my server with sudo sh start.sh, but when I'm trying to connect to the server it says that modules are not found, so that means it is using the other interpreter. When I do sudo pip3 install hello-world, then I pass one module not found error. btw I have a .env folder with all the modules installed in my application.

Comment: instead of stardard `/usr/bin/python3` you have to use `/your/venv/folder/python3` and it will have access to modules installed in `venv` - OR you would have to first activate `venv` to get this path with `which python3`

Comment: I'm only checking what is the output of sh when I launch it and it gives me the default python3 location. I know what you mean

Comment: I have already activated it

Comment: if venv is activated then `which python` should show you different path to Python. And when you use venv then you don't use `sudo` to install modules. `sudo` will install in global/standard Python but Python in venv doesn't use modules installed for standard Python. it need own modules installed with `pip` (or `pip3`) after activation venv

Comment: What command should I use in .sh file to activate the venv?

Comment: It should works the same `source venv/bin/activate` which you use to activate venv in shell. But I usually use `/your/venv/folder/python3 my_script.py` to run my script with with Python installed in `venv` and then it uses modules installed in `venv`

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate VENV

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $(dirname $0)
. venv/bin/activate
export FLASK_APP=wsgi.py
export SECRET_KEY=test
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
export APP_CONFIG_FILE=config.py
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=80
which python3
flask run
```

^ Try this, you can run it from any directory.